# Accessing shared Outlook folders on my Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, exchange

I have worked out how to access my work emails via the Microsoft Exchange Server and also access any meeting requests. However any of the calendar entries on our shared calendar cannot be accessed.

I've tried [Touchdown](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nitrodesk.droid20.nitroid&hl=en) without success as it does not support shared folders. We are an events company that needs to be kept informed in what each of us are doing (along with our rosters) so I have no use for my own personal work calendar entries.

The iPhones can do it, what is the problem with the Androids?

Answer (score 1):

Currently android doesn't have native support for multiple calendars, your phone is working just fine. The Touchdown app is awful, avoid it like the plague.
Basically, the calendar, mail account and everything associated with your personal account are a single item. It may be possible to add the account that relates to the shared calendar as a second Exchange account on your Samsung and access the calendar that way.
Of course if it's a colleague's inbox that's not practical. Maybe talk to your IT about setting up a dedicated team calendar that anyone has access to?
You can definitely add a second exchange account to your phone, you could do this to access the new team calendar.
Worth a try?

Comment: Thanks. I just found a product called codetwo that needs to be loaded onto the company server and it's about $500 so I like your option and will give it a try first!

Comment: @Martino do u have any recommendation for an android client besides touchdown? Thank you!